# Sum of Fibonacci-Numbers

Tags: summation, fibonacci-numbers

Is there a closed formula for the sum of the first $n$ even (or odd) Fibonacci numbers, like there is one for the $n$th number (Moivre-Binet)?

Comment: Yes, there are formulae for $\sum\limits_{k=0}^m F_{k\cdot n + r}$. The formula for the sums of even Fibonacci numbers ($n = 3,\; r = 0$) is simple.

Comment: See http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/52707.html

Comment: Of course, what I mean is some explicit formula. What I want to do is to calculate this sum without calculating all neccessary Fibonaci numbers, so that I can calculate the sum in constant time for large $n$

Comment: @AEdwards thanks for the link, but I want to sum up only the even numbers.

Comment: Do you mean the even Fibonacci numbers, or do you mean the Fibonacci numbers with even indices?

Comment: Add the Binet formulae for the odds or evens by summing the geometric progressions which arise. Write out the first few terms to see what is going on.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott the even numbers. But the sum of numbers with even indices would be interesting too.

Comment: Further to @BrianM.Scott's comment - note that every third Fibonacci number is even, so that gives a GP too. The odd numbers can be summed as two GPs (or as the sum of all the numbers less the sum of the even ones).

Comment: Even indices are easy: $\sum_{k=0}^nF_{2k}=F_{2n+1}-1$, and $\sum_{k=0}^nF_{2k+1}=F_{2k+2}$.

Comment: thanks, I will try it that way

Comment: $$\sum_{k=0}^n F_{3k} = \frac{F_{3n+2}-1}{2}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $F_n$ is even iff $n\equiv 0\pmod 3$ because the Fibonacci recursion modulo $2$ gives the sequence $0,1,1,0,1,1,\ldots$

So we want to find a closed expression for 
$$s_n=\sum_{k=0}^n F_{3k}.$$
We find the recursion (why?)
$$s_{n+1} = 4s_n+s_{n-1}+2 $$
and from this 
$$ s_n =a(2+\sqrt 5)^n+b(2-\sqrt 5)^n -\frac12$$
where $a,b$ can be determined from the cases $n=0$ and $n=1$, for example.

Comment: Note that because $F_{3k}=F_{3k-1}+F_{3k-2}$ it is particularly easy to sum the odd numbers once the sum of the evens is known.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\varphi=\frac12\left(1+\sqrt5\right)$ and $\widehat\varphi=\frac12\left(1-\sqrt5\right)$, so that $F_n=\frac1{\sqrt5}\left(\varphi^n-\widehat\varphi^n\right)$. Then

$$\varphi^3=\left(\frac{1+\sqrt5}2\right)^3=2+\sqrt5\qquad\text{and}\qquad\widehat\varphi^3=\left(\frac{1-\sqrt5}2\right)^3=2-\sqrt5\;,$$

so the sum of the first $n$ even Fibonacci numbers is

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}F_{3k}&=\frac1{\sqrt5}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\varphi^{3k}-\widehat\varphi^{3k}\right)\\\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt5}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\varphi^{3k}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\widehat\varphi^{3k}\right)\\\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt5}\left(\frac{\varphi^{3n}-1}{\varphi^3-1}-\frac{\widehat\varphi^{3n}-1}{\widehat\varphi^3-1}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{(2+\sqrt5)^n-1}{5+\sqrt5}-\frac{1-(2-\sqrt5)^n}{5-\sqrt5}\\\\
&=\frac{(2+\sqrt5)^n}{5+\sqrt5}+\frac{(2-\sqrt5)^n}{5-\sqrt5}-\left(\frac1{5+\sqrt5}+\frac1{5-\sqrt5}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{(2+\sqrt5)^n}{5+\sqrt5}+\frac{(2-\sqrt5)^n}{5-\sqrt5}-\frac12\;.
\end{align*}$$

Moreover, $2-\sqrt5\approx-0.23607$, and $5-\sqrt5\approx2.76393$, so even for $n=1$ the middle term is only about $-0.08541$, and it decreases rapidly as $n$ increases. Thus, you want the integer nearest

$$\frac{(2+\sqrt5)^n}{5+\sqrt5}-\frac12\;,$$

which is

$$\left\lfloor\frac{(2+\sqrt5)^n}{5+\sqrt5}\right\rfloor\;.$$